# Why Linux creates temp files without extension when you upload file with PHP, and Windows makes with extension?

Tags: php, linux, windows, temp

I'm using PHP 7.0 and 7.2 with both UBUNTU 18.0 TLS and Windows 10,

I have a script that normally uploads files and process its content,

the behavior I'm asking about is that on Ubuntu, the temp file that created for the uploaded file is created without an extension like the below :

```
path: "/tmp"
filename: "phpdvdVPB"
basename: "phpdvdVPB"
pathname: "/tmp/phpdvdVPB"
extension: ""
```

but on Windows, the created temp file is made with an extension like :

```
"dirname" => "C:\xampp\tmp"
"basename" => "php34E6.tmp"
"extension" => "tmp"
"filename" => "php34E6"
```

And the same result happens when you use tempnam() PHP method that creates temp file, it will create the file without extension on Linux, but Windows will have the extension.

**So my question is, why Linux creates temp files without extensions, and Windows yes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.TMP has no programmatic meaning on Windows, the extension is usually not registered. It is however a common convention for temporary files to have this extension so that users know that these files are safe to delete.

DOS and old Windows versions do not support automatic deletion of files when the last handle is closed so if an application crashes it might be unable to delete its temporary files.

PHP is probably using the [`GetTempFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettempfilenamew) function which adds this extension for you automatically. This function takes care of creating a unique filename for you.

There is actually a way to mark temporary files on Windows but this functionality is not really exposed to the end-user. Files can be marked with the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` attribute. This tells Windows to not write the content to disk unless required by the memory manager during paging.

I don't have a canonical documentation reference that says that all .TMP files are temp files, this is old history and done by convention.

In addition to the `GetTempFileName` function using this extension, [KB 92635](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/92635/windows-temporary-files) says:

> A number of files may appear on the hard drive in various directories beginning with a tilde character (~) and ending with a .TMP extension. These may be temporary files created by Windows that remain on the hard drive due to an irregular exit from a Windows session.
>
> Under normal conditions, these files are closed and deleted by Windows when you quit a Windows session. However, if you quit Windows in an irregular way (for example, restarting the computer or turning it off during an active Windows session) the files are not closed or deleted.
>
> ...
>
> To delete a temporary file, use the following steps:
>
> ...
>
> Delete any existing .TMP files. Make sure Windows is not running at the time these files are deleted. Some of these .TMP files may be files that Windows is using.

This document is aimed at Windows 2 and 3. The ~ prefix is optional and ~ is used in the compatibility short-name on Windows 95 and later.

Comment: the extension is usually not registered ?? what it's meant, and why you didn't mention anything related to Linux, do you need to prove that this is a custom way in Windows OS to mark temp files with .temp extension for safe delete, and Linux doesn't work by this way ?

Comment: Not registered means that there is no `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tmp` entry in the registry. I tried to explain the history of this on Windows. On Linux applications can always call unlink to make sure the file is deleted.

Comment: I know that Linux can call unlink to delete, but why you mention the idea of delete here in both cases? I still not understand if you need to prove that Windows uses this extension only for safe delete temp files and to be markable always or there are additional purposes bro ?

Comment: I edited the question adding quotes from the most canonical source I know.

Comment: why the entire answer is related to the idea of deleting temp file? you added much to my knowledge, but I don't know still the certain answer to my question, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: I tried to explain where the .TMP convention comes from, I don't understand what more information you need. Unix/Linux and Windows do things differently. At the end of the day, why do you care what PHP does? Just use the filename you are given and stop worrying about it.

Comment: that's what I was trying to understand, thanks alot, green mark :) <3 .